# occurrences of any letters / javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am playing around with dom manipulation and js and I am running into a problem.

Let's say I have `<p id = "description"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras facilisis, felis et sagittis eleifend, justo ante maximus augue, id porta massa elit a ligula. </p>`

and I want to write a function that counts a number of repeated letters in a paragraph. I figured out how to do that with a string but not with paragraphs.

```
    function recurringLetters() {
      var myParagraph = document.getElementById("description").innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

This is how far I have gotten.

Comment: what do you mean how to do it with strings not paragraphs? A paragraph is a string

Comment: Robbie. This is working no problem var myString = "This is my string.";
console.log(myString.split("i").length - 1);

My problem is I cannot get <p id = description> Text </p> to work on any given letter

Answer (score 0):

**Hope This Answers your Question**.
Just Copy & Paste into an HTML file for testing.

```js
function WORD_COUNT( _THIS_ , _WORD_ ){
var TEMP = _THIS_.innerHTML;
var COUNT= 0;
// IF TEMP search result finds nothing, return is -1, so -1 is our stopping point
while(TEMP.search(_WORD_)>-1){
    TEMP = TEMP.replace(_WORD_,'');
    COUNT++;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=COUNT;
}}
```

```html
<p onmouseover=WORD_COUNT(this,'us');>PUT YOUR MOUSE OVER ME.<BR> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras facilisis, felis et sagittis eleifend, justo ante maximus augue, id porta massa elit a ligula. </p>

<p ID=output>Output area<p>
```